# Ruby how to modify a instance variable from another method?

Tags: ruby

Basically, i need to increase by one my variable `variable_position` every time the method `set_variable_value` is called, so every `bin_val` variable created through that method gets created with a different incremental `variable_position` parameter starting from 16.

Right know, it goes from 15 (see initialize method) to 16 in the first method call, but then i stays at 16 no matter how many times the method is called.

```
require "./my_math.rb"
    class Rules
      attr_accessor :variable_position
      JUMP_ARR = [";JGT", ";JEQ", ";JGE", ";JLT", ";JNE", ";JLE", ";JMP"]

      def initialize
        @variable_position = 15
      end

      # A instructions have to be 16 bit long
      def self.a_16_bit (line)
        a_rules = Rules.new
        if line[1] == 'R'
          bin_val = a_rules.set_reserved_variable_value(line)
        elsif (/^[[:alpha:]]+$/).match(line[1..line.length])
          bin_val = a_rules.set_variable_value #HERE IS WHERE I CALL THE METHOD
        else
          bin_val = MyMath.to_binary(line[1..line.length])
        end
        n = bin_val.to_s.length
        m = 16 - n
        complete_number = ("0"*m) + bin_val.to_s
      end

      def set_variable_value
        @variable_position += 1 #HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO INCREASE THE VALUE
        bin_val = MyMath.to_binary(@variable_position)
      end
    end
```

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: Please share the caller code. This class looks fine.

Comment: @mudasobwa is right in the self.a_16_bit method; I added a comment so you can find it easier

Comment: @SebastianDelgado after calling `::a_16_bit` a new `Rules` object is created. So every time you call that method, you are initializing a new object, with a new instance variable. Plus you call it only once from within `::a_16_bit`, so it can change only by `1`. Maybe `@variable_position` should be a class instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need an instance of the object at all:

```
require "./my_math.rb"
class Rules
  JUMP_ARR = [";JGT", ";JEQ", ";JGE", ";JLT", ";JNE", ";JLE", ";JMP"]

  @variable_position = 15

  # A instructions have to be 16 bit long
  def self.a_16_bit (line)
    bin_val = if line[1] == 'R'
                # code from set_reserved_variable_value(line) here
              elsif (/^[[:alpha:]]+$/).match(line[1..line.length])
                MyMath.to_binary(@variable_position += 1)
              else
                MyMath.to_binary(line[1..line.length])
              end
    n = bin_val.to_s.length
    m = 16 - n
    complete_number = ("0"*m) + bin_val.to_s
  end
end
```

In your current code you are messing with instance variables and class methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

When you call `a_rules = Rules.new` you are creating a new instance of Rules. So the constructor `initialize` is setting the `@variable_position` value to 15 once for every instance.

Then, when you call the method `bin_val = a_rules.set_variable_value` it increases the value of `@variable_position` once because you are still working on the same instance.

I suggest that `@variable_position` should be a class variable. That way you won't be resetting it's value every time you instance a new object.

Comment: Thanks for your help